# how to download image in data/data/application folder in android using cordova

Tags: android, file, cordova

I want my cordova(3.3.0) application to download image in my application storage         (data/data/com.exp.abc),but I am not able to find out any solution for this. I integrated file and file transfer plugin and it is working fine with sdcard storage but i want my application to store data in application local storage.I already tried

```
**var filepath = "data/data/com.exp.abc";
  var filepath = "Android/data/com.exp.abc";
  var filepath = "data/data/com.exp.abc";
  var filepath = "file:///android_asstes/www/img";**
```

above all giving file not found error,while this stores file in sdcard in place of internal storage

```
 **var target = "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/img/";**
```

I also tried to change

```
 **window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSS, failS);**
```

to

```
**window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFSS, failS);**
```

but again it doesn't work for me.anyone can help me with this?????

Comment: If download success, you should re-scan your device storage, because Cordova does not know if the file is downloaded. so i made a plugin , It is a plugin that updates the gallery after downloading. [cordova-plugin-gallery-refresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-gallery-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and could not find an answer anywhere on the web.

Heres the answer to anyone who requires it. Its using angular... but you should be able to use it in standard javascript.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DownloadProductsCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$cordovaFile, $cordovaProgress) {
var uri = "http://your_domain/file_name";
// for sqlite databases
var file_path = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/../../../data/data/<your-app-id>/databases/filename.sqlite.db";
//for files 
var file_path = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/../../../data/data/<your-app-id>/filename.ext";

//using ngcordova to download the file
                  $cordovaFile
                    .downloadFile(uri, file_path, true, {})
                    .then(function (result) {
                        // Success!
                        $cordovaProgress.hide();
                        console.log("Finished Downloading", result);
                        $state.transitionTo('home');
                    }, function (err) {
                        // Error
                        console.log(err);
                    }, function (progress) {
                        $scope.perc = Math.floor(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
                        $scope.progress_bar = $scope.perc + "% Downloaded";

                    });
})
```